# Trigger useEffect when other components state variable changes

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, setstate

I am trying to trigger a `useEffect` in one of my components, when the state variable of another changes.

I have implemented web sockets into my app, and basically want to perform some action when the web socket is triggered. I have the web socket side of things covered and working right now.

This is a basic breakdown of what is going on:

**HomeScreen**

```
...
const {
    shouldFetchApplications,
    setShouldFetchApplications
} = useWebSockets();
...
useEffect(() => {
   console.log(shouldFetchApplications)
   // Other code
}, [shouldFetchApplications])
...
```

**WebSocket**

```
...
const {
    setShouldFetchApplications,
} = useWebSockets()
...
const onTaskUpdate = () => {
    setShouldFetchApplications(true)
};
...
```

**useWebSockets**

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

const useWebSockets = () => {
  const [shouldFetchApplications, setShouldFetchApplications] = useState<boolean>(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('useWebSockets')
    console.log(shouldFetchApplications)
  }, [shouldFetchApplications, setShouldFetchApplications])

  return {
    shouldFetchApplications,
    setShouldFetchApplications,
  }
}

export default useWebSockets
```

When my web socket is triggered, it updates `shouldFetchApplications` to be true, but the `useEffect` in `HomeScreen` never triggers, I know `setState` is async, but I don't see why this would be an issue.

Any ideas on how I trigger the `useEffect` in my `HomeScreen` component?

Comment: Can you reproduce your issue using https://codesandbox.io/?

Comment: "set" functions from `useState` are absolutely not `async`

Comment: @possum set functions from useState are most definitely asynchronous. Explained nicely [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/the-usestate-set-method-is-not-reflecting-a-change-immediately).

Comment: I understand what you're posting, but that's not what asynchronous means in a javascript context and being imprecise on what asynchronous means causes confusion.  They trigger side effects which occur later, but the functions themselves are not asynchronous.  They do not have the `async` in their signature and they are not to be awaited.

Comment: @possum indeed, terminology is important, however, I think given the context and code snippets it's quite clear that TreyCollier isn't referring to whether the `set` function returns a promise, but rather to the fact that the update is **not** performed synchronously (which is 100% correct). Therefore, your comment is more likely to confuse people, particularly newer coders, and mislead them instead of properly explaining the nuance.

Answer (score 0):

I have since found an alternate solution to my above problem, and have since realised why my code above did not work.

I of course created my own custom hook `useWebSockets`, which I then was importing into `HomeScreen` and `WebSocket`, but failed to realise that each were creating their own instance of `useWebSockets`, and as a result, `HomeScreen` would never see a change in the `shouldFetchApplications` value when updated by `WebSocket`